# Android - Image Gallery (using Universal-image-loader)

Tags: android, image, url, image-gallery, universal-image-loader

I wonder if there are any libraries/tutorials on how to create a simple Image Gallery where the images are loaded from URLs.

What i want:

- A gridview to see thumbs of all images in the gallery
- When you click an image you see it fullscreen
- Swipe left/right to browse through the images in the gallery

Can't seem to get it right!

EDIT:
This Universal Image Loader looks great
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
is it possible to use the ImageGridActivity in my other activity? How?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is, you should look at **Universal Image Loader for Android** which is a very good library for handling images from the network.

**Features**

- Multithread image loading
- Possibility of wide tuning ImageLoader's configuration (thread pool
  size, HTTP options, memory and disc cache, display image options, and
  others)
- Possibility of image caching in memory and/or on device's file
  sysytem (or SD card)
- Possibility to "listen" loading process
- Possibility to customize every display image call with separated
  options
- Widget support

Project site located at github: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

**Edit**

The project comes with examples that meet your wishes, Gallery, ListView, GridView and PagerAdapter.

Comment: This looks great, but i need help implementing it. How do i run the examples?

Comment: Create a new project in Eclipse and copy the contents from the `sample` folder to the Eclipse project folder (*AndroidManifest.xml*, folders **assets**, **libs**, **res** and **src**).

Comment: To import sample project in Eclipse: File -> New -> Other | -> Android -> **Android Project from Existing Code**. Choose "sample" folder.

Answer (score 0):

The best bet would be to store all the images from a url to external storage and then generate thumbnails asynchronously to optimize performance. But for that you also need all urls of the images on the webpage which is easy to do using html parsers.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

String html = "";
InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    str.append(line);
}
in.close();
html = str.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

For displaying images in the grid you will need a custom adapter (Google it)
and using bundle send the bitmap to a new activity there u will be displaying your image in full screen.